# Get current url in Django View

Tags: django, django-views

I need to grab the domain for the current page in my Django view. `build_absolute_uri()` works great to get the full path (http://www.domain.com/path/to/somewhere) but is there anyway to just simply get the http://www.domain.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a combination of `HttpRequest.get_host()` to get the host:port ("www.domain.com") and `HttpRequest.is_secure()` to see if the request was made over http or https. This should allow you to reconstruct a URL like https://www.domain.com:8080